# Creating a lookup field in a CakePHP form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a view created using Bake that has the following:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit Device'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('DeviceID');
    echo $this->Form->input('DeviceTypeID');
    echo $this->Form->input('UserID');
    echo $this->Form->input('Type');
    echo $this->Form->input('KeyPadID');
    echo $this->Form->input('Version');
    echo $this->Form->input('Description');
    echo $this->Form->input('UpdateID');
?>
</fieldset>
```

Which saves to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `device` (
    `DeviceID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `DeviceTypeID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `UserID` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
    `Type` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `KeyPadID` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `Version` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `Description` TINYBLOB NULL ,
    `UpdateID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`DeviceID`),
    INDEX `FK_USER` (`UserID`),
    INDEX `FK_devices_updates` (`UpdateID`),
    INDEX `FK_device_devicetype` (`DeviceTypeID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_device_devicetype` FOREIGN KEY (`DeviceTypeID`) REFERENCES `devicetype` (`DeviceTypeID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_devices_updates` FOREIGN KEY (`UpdateID`) REFERENCES `update` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_USER` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `user` (`UserID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

My problem is that when the form is displayed, it shows DeviceTypeID and UserID as well as UpdateID as the foreign key value instead of a drop down with the caption being the text and the value being the ID column. How would I go about setting a field from the foreign table to be the display field and the id as being the value?

Answer (score 2):

**Update 11-02-2013**

First of all I strongly suggest to convert your primary and foreign keys accordingly
so that they meet the CakePHP naming conventions.

This means that:

- `DeviceID` should be `id`.
- `DeviceTypeID` should be `device_type_id`
- `UserID` should be `user_id`

Also all primary keys in your tables should be named as `id`.
This way you will never have to worry about anything, concerning your models etc.

After that, all your tables must be in **plural** form. This means that `device` table should be `devices`, so you should rename it also. 
I assume that you also have the following tables: `devices_types` and `users`.

At this point, I should notice that I would prefer to have a table    named `devicetype`. I avoid underscored names, because it's very easy  to make mistakes using the correct form  for each object, class etc.   So I don't have to worry whether I should use the CamelCase or not.

Anyway

Your `Device` model should be something like that:

```
<?php
/** Device.php **/
class Device extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Device';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'DeviceType' => array(
            'className' => 'DeviceType',
            'foreignKey' => 'device_type_id'
            /** Specify other keys that meet your needs **/
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
};
?>
```

Also your `DeviceType` model should be similar to

```
<?php
/** DeviceType.php **/
class DeviceType extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'DeviceType';
};
```

In your `edit()` method, you should query your `DeviceType` in something like this:

```
...
$devicetypes = $this->Device->DeviceType->find('list', array('id', 'caption'));
$this->set(compact('devicetypes'));
...
```

This way in your view the respective form element sets the `<select>` menu correctly.

PS: You should follow the CakePHP conventions about model-naming etc... Mine was just an example.

Comment: +1 for the cake conventions. If this is *not* an existing database naming tables and columns according to the CakePHP conventions, will make sure that CakePHP will automatically find the database table and relations. Otherwise you'll have to specify the table to use and the foreign-key fields yourself (it *is* possible, but using conventions saves a lot of time and possible problems)

Comment: Also CakePHP only officially supports 'auto number' and 'guid' (char36)) columns as Primary Key. Manually entering a Primary Key *may not work* because CakePHP will try to find an existing record with that ID and 'stop' the save because it couldn't be found; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: @thaJeztah I created auto increment columns now just to insure they don't cause me problems.

Comment: @chris-sawfish I did as you recommended. Now i get **Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: D:\wamp\www\meaadmin\Controller\DevicesController.php 
Line: 78**

Comment: line 78 has `$devicetypes = $this->Device->DeviceType->find('list', array('DeviceTypeID', 'Type'));`

Comment: @chris-sawfish could you please add the new database-schema *and* the code of your models to your answer? You may need to add a 'belongsTo' relation to the Device model

Comment: Sorry for the big delay... I've updated my post. So if the problem persists, check the solution I propose